# Формат ввода в поле NSTextField

Tags: cocoa, objective-c, форматирование

Есть поле NSTextField и нужно сделать так, чтоб в него можно было вводить только цифры и, чтоб они имели такой вид: "123-456-789"

Эту задачу я решил NSNumberFormatter:

```
NSString *myString = @"12345678";
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
[formatter setGroupingSeparator:@"-"];
[formatter setGroupingSize:3];
[formatter setMaximumIntegerDigits:9];
NSString *formattedOutput = [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:[myString intValue]]];
```

Но проблема в том, что форматирование проходит не справа, а слева, то есть имеем:

"12-345-678",

а нужно чтоб было так: "123-456-78"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не знаю, как это должно быть реализованно при помощи NSNumberFormatter, но можно ведь вручную добавлять разделитель. 
Вот как-то так:

```
// field - поле ввода (NSTextField)
NSMutableString *temp = [NSMutableString stringWithString:[field stringValue]];

int index=3;
if ([temp length] <=3) {
    return;
}
while (index < [temp length]) {
    [temp insertString:@"-" atIndex:index];
    index +=4;
}
```

Ну а если, конечно, возможен ввод только 8 или 9 цифр, тогда предыдущее решение более удобное.

Comment: для полного счастья нужно скрестить вот с этим примером http://chamelo.co.uk/textfield-validation

Comment: это как это именно?

Comment: вот мой как я его адаптировал под мои нужды http://dl.dropbox.com/u/298332/trash/TextFormatter.zip

Answer (score 0):

Что-то не пойму где формируется порядок ***-***-**<br/>
Но по логике, если <br/>
***-***-** => **-***-***<br/> 
то можно сделать наоборот<br/>
**-***-*** => ***-***-**<br/> 
и получить на выходе то, что нужно =)<br/>
**P.S.:** Чуть позже попаду за комп и попробую разобраться

**UPD.**

```
[numberFormatter setPositiveFormat:@"###-###-##"];
```

Comment: Это задает разделитель: `[formatter setGroupingSeparator:@"-"];`.
Это указывает сколько цифр в группе: `[formatter setGroupingSize:3];`.

Comment: Попробуйте setPositiveFormat.

Comment: Не работает.

Comment: Так и не получилось решить проблему.

Comment: А вот тот вариант, что я предложил, - поясните, почему не подходит?

Comment: ох, вот только что склеел ваш совет с этим примером http://chamelo.co.uk/textfield-validation и получилось. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Тебе нужно отслеживать ввод символов с помощью NSNotification и после каждых 3 символов вставлять "-".
При получении фокуса проходишься по тексту и удаляешь "-"
После окончания ввода также проходишься и добавляешь  "-"